# Set the height of Details section Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

The no of items in my invoice never gets more than 10. When its only one item in invoice(one row in details section) the report footer shows very up.

I want that I should fix 10 rows for the details section, when there are less rows, the remaining rows to make it 10 should be showed as blank lines.

I need the footer to appear at the same place all the time, irrespective of how many items are there in the invoice(never gets more than 10).

Please suggest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just use Sub Report and Fix the height of the sub report 
then you will be able to display fix page.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you are asking, but I will make some guesses with possible solutions.

If you print multiple invoices per report, you can group on the invoice designator, and set the report to start every invoice on a new page.  In addition, you can force a new page when the record count goes over 10 rows.  There are various ways to do this, but the simplest would be to add a counter that is set/reset at the start of an invoice, and then conditionally force a "new page before" if that counter reaches 11.  You can also set this to force a new page for every n + 1 records (the 11th record, the 21st record, the 31st record, etc.)

If you just don't want the report footer to show up, you can either suppress it or issue a "new page before" on report footer.  This is handy if you keep a summary page for reference (# of invoices in run, total balances, etc.).

If you just don't want a floating footer, you can select "print at bottom of page" for any section.  This is handy for group totals.  That, with "Repeat Group Header on Each Page", you can get some very nice looking invoices.

Comment: What is that you didnt understand? There will be 10 and only 10 lines in the details section(each line representing an item in invoice).If there are less lines(due to lesss items in an invoice), still there shall be 10 lines in invoice, the remaining will be blank lines. This is just to make sure that the invoice appears consistent. the fooler, which shows the total bill amount will appear at exactly the same place, whether its 10 items or 5. This should be good to help u understand :)

Comment: Then, did my answer help you?  What I didn't understand is whether there is additional logic to provide limitations on invoice items, whether grouping was required, etc.  If you are controlling the # of invoice items externally (through your logic, etc.) then the above should help.  If you are printing ONLY a single invoice at a time, it can be even easier, by expanding the page footer or report footer and dropping your subtotals, etc., in that.  It's always in the same place all the time.  ;-)    Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

to fix height of detail section ..suppose i want size of 8 rows/records then 
right click on detail section ->section expert ->on paging tab-> check on New page before beside button (x+2) write formula below given..

IF Remainder (RecordNumber, 8) = 0 THEN
    TRUE
ELSE
    FALSE

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is really stale, but here's how to do what the OP asked.

You need to do 2 things. Find out the amount of real estate you need on the page for the 10 rows, and create a group footer that is that size directly beneath the detail line (e.g 2" or 5 cm).

Then, go into the section expert for the detail line and check the *Underlay Following Sections* box.

If you are ever going to have more than 10 detail lines, you also need to go to New Page after on the Paging tab and put in 10.

Answer (score 0):

Put all fields Top = 0

Decrease section height.
Now, you have to set fields top dynamically.

Like this:

```
cr.Section1.ReportObjects.Item("Line1").Top = 0
cr.Section1.ReportObjects.Item("Line2").Top = cr.Section1.ReportObjects.Item("Line1").Top + cr.Section1.ReportObjects.Item("Line1").Height
```